# Can 冒険する translate as "to venture"?

Tags: translation, word-choice, words

It's the closest verb I can think to use as "to venture". Specifically when using it in a context like ーへと冒険していく。 To venture into...

Is this correct? Or is there a better/more natural verb I could use? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

冒険 is a word that is associated with "real" adventures into the deep sea, outer space, etc., and the primarily translation of 冒険する is "to have an adventure". Something like 未開のジャングルへと冒険していく is perfectly fine. On the other hand, something like ヨーロッパ市場へと冒険していく is understandable but usually sounds a bit too grandiose. Instead, you may want to say ヨーロッパ市場へと足を踏み入れる, ヨーロッパ市場に挑戦する, 思い切ってヨーロッパ市場に進出する, etc.